# Extract lat and lon from a string

Tags: php

I have got the following string

```
http://www.domain.com/map.aspx?isTrafficAlert=true&lat=51.529900&lon=-0.785384
```

I need to extract lat and lon from this string.

I got lat=51.529900 and lon=-0.785384 using the following code

```
$str = "http://www.domain.com/map.aspx?isTrafficAlert=true&lat=51.529900&lon=-0.785384";
list(,$lat,$lon) = explode("&",$str);
```

But then can't get the number.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `parse_str` along with `parse_url` like as

```
parse_str(parse_url($str, PHP_URL_QUERY), $latlon);
echo $latlon['lat'];
echo $latlon['lon'];
```

Comment: Getting undefined index on lat and lon.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra have you put `$str = "http://www.domain.com/map.aspx?isTrafficAlert=true&lat=51.529900&lon=-0.785384";` on top, yeah?

Comment: Yes :)....It's all there.

Comment: works for me, https://3v4l.org/CGYUI

Comment: For me too https://3v4l.org/tWWT2

Comment: hmm..I ran it in a separate file and worked but when I am running inside a loop then it is breaking....must be something from my end. I am very much sure about that. However thanks a lot Uchiha for your help. Learnt a new function name.

Comment: You're Welcome. Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "http://www.domain.com/map.aspx?isTrafficAlert=true&lat=51.529900&lon=-0.785384";

$var = parse_str($str, $array);

$lat = $array['lat'];
$lon = $array['lon'];
```

Comment: Some explanation is usually appreciated

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$str = "http://www.domain.com/map.aspx?isTrafficAlert=true&lat=51.529900&lon=-0.785384";

parse_str($str,$params);
print_r($params);
```

LAT: `$params['lat'];`
LON: `$params['lon'];`

Hope it help;

Comment: what does this answer provide, that the other 3 did not?

Comment: I did it few minutes after you and did not notice yours...